# How to save whole page as one file so that it works offline (including external javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to be able to save a page on my website to my harddrive, so that i can use it both online and offline. The thing is, the page uses references to javascript and CSS files outside it's own folder. It is very important that i can save the whole page as one .html file, so that all the javascript and CSS code from the external files are in that file as well.

Is there a way to do this?

This should be programatically

Comment: I assume that you have tried the "Save as web archive" functions of the various browsers and they don't do it?

Comment: I have tried with Chrome. I can choose save as whole website, which creates more than 1 file. I can also choose save as html, but it doesnt have CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: IE can save page as "web-archive" (.mht) file. But FF cannot open .mht file, for example.

Comment: Why cannot it be more than one file?

Comment: This is the demand from my boss. It looks more neat with 1 file i guess.

Comment: Do you have dreamweaver? If so download and use all the files to make an air app that will allow you to browse the page offline.

Or download all the files and in the places where they are linked ie: `<script src=""/>` you could put the script there like so: `<script>script goes here</script>`

Answer (score 0):

As you request, this can be done programmatically with lets say Python.
The pattern of the code would look like this:

- Request the user to paste the url in a box
- wget or curl the page and use regex to find out where the included codes are
- - OR: use a library like SGML to interact with the HTML tags directly
- Put all the linked CSS, JS etc. files in a List
- Fetch all the linked files their contents and put them in a List
- Rebuild the HTML source code and strip out the   and  tags stuff
- Now loop the linked files's contents in the  tags like this:

  newHeaderContent = ''

  for content in linkedFilesArray:
      newHeaderContent = newHeaderContent + content

  newHTML = firstHTMLCode + newHeaderContent + lastHTMLCode